# AskUbuntu pages are returning an error when connected to Opera's built in VPN

Tags: support

The issue is simple.

When I navigate to: [Why do pages not load in any browser after updating Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167389/why-do-pages-not-load-in-any-browser-after-updating-ubuntu-12-04)

I can load it as expected.

When I toggle on Opera's built in VPN I get:
Page Not Found
We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

My external IP address when connected to the VPN is: 135.84.127.153

Can we get this whitelisted or is it working as intended?

Opera info:
40.0.2308.62 - Opera is up to date

System:
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (x86_64; Unity)

Browser identification:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36 OPR/40.0.2308.62

EDIT: Funny enough - meta.askubuntu.com loads just fine. Looks like it's just askubuntu.com pages that don't work.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/sofu-rejecting-requests-coming-from-opera-if-turbo-mode-is-on

Comment: What about other SE pages like http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @MarkKirby both root domains load fine. SU questions do NOT load. Unix questions do. So kind of a mixed bag really.

Comment: IDK what to tell you? I up voted to try get some attention on this but, as it effects multiple sites, it may get a better response at http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarkKirby Am I the only one on SO using Opera? Usually when you're the only one in the world with a problem the problem is on your end...

Comment: @anon58192932 I think most of us prefer Chrome or Firefox, especially after that whole Opera password manager leak thing.

Comment: @anon58192932 you should also read the post Nathan linked.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I read the post. That seems like a different feature of Opera's ? They work similarly - they are both Opera provided services which funnel network traffic for multiple users through a single IP address. However I don't make any other immediate connections.

Comment: @MarkKirby after debugging a little further it appears HTTP vs HTTPS related. meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285306/unable-to-load-various-pages-via-http-across-stackexchange-domains-while-connect

Comment: Not the only one it seems http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16179/why-so-many-404-page-not-found-errors

Comment: Something about the Opera VPN doesn't work with StackExchange right.  There are at least a dozen reports of this on Meta.SE so I'm not sure how relevant this is going to be here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Opera 42(Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/42.0.2393.94). Haven't found any solution on web, but it is actually simple enough: just go for https instead of http, i.e. you get from google link like this:

> [How do I move (copy) my entire Ubuntu system to a different hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-system-to-a-different-hard-disk)

which doesn't load properly(no such page error), so you need to edit it to use https:

> [How do I move (copy) my entire Ubuntu system to a different hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-system-to-a-different-hard-disk)

and now everything is fine.
The same works with superuser, stackexchange and i suppose many others sites.