# Why so many 404 page not found errors?

Tags: support

I am meeting `404 page not found` errors very often on askubuntu in the last days. I mean, much more often than I'd expect, more often than it used to be, more often than on other stackexchange sites. For instance, I just requested [this unexisting page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833102/copy-only-copy-not-cutting-in-nano) clicking on a *Hot Network Question* link.

Is it me, or the site?

Comment: Six questions down http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16157/askubuntu-pages-are-returning-an-error-when-connected-to-operas-built-in-vpn

Answer (score 2):

It was me.

I was using [Opera's VPN](http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2016/04/free-vpn-integrated-opera-for-windows-mac/) and, I don't know why, that seems to be a problem. When I turn it off, I can find the pages.