# my profile page on AskUbuntu is 'Page not found'

Tags: support

Today I logged in AskUbuntu to find that my profile page is missing. To visit my profile page I clicked on my small avatar in top bar to see it is not found (Please see screen shot below)[image]

It is because I broke some rule on AskUbuntu? which I highly doubt, because I have been inactive on this website for a month or so, in this case I believe I should have received a message from any moderator which I didn't. OR Is it anything wrong with website itself? BTW, I am able to visit my profile page on Unix & Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Is this repeatable? I just checked and can access your profile with no problem.

Comment: @terdon repeatable on opera with both url http://askubuntu.com/users/294611/edward-torvalds and http://askubuntu.com/users/294611

Comment: @terdon I think something wrong with opera, my page loads fine in firefox. thanks anyway

Comment: This may be related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16157/askubuntu-pages-are-returning-an-error-when-connected-to-operas-built-in-vpn

Comment: The problem is the VPN that you have activated by using Opera, instead of " HTTP" , use " HTTPS"  in the URL and it will work.

Comment: @nisevi thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce this. When I visit the URL you did:

```
http://askubuntu.com/users/294611/
```

I'm redirected to:

```
http://askubuntu.com/users/294611/edward-torvalds
```

And your profile loads.

You can disable "server-side" redirects in many browsers but you wouldn't see the 404 page. The server only sends a plaintext-redirect:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/users/294611/edward-torvalds">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Are you still seeing this issue? Does `curl http://askubuntu.com/users/294611/` show the markup above, or the longer 404? That might help differentiate a network-level issue (proxy, bad cache, etc) from a browser bork.

---

So this looks like the proxy or browser interfering with the URL. The pages actually reflect the URL back in their content. If you view the source of the page, there should be a tag like this in the header.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://askubuntu.com/123123"/>
```

Compare that to the URL you thought you were visiting. Use that as the basis for reporting a bug to the people who maintain the proxy, or write the browser.

Comment: curl shows 'object moved'

Comment: I think something wrong with opera, my page loads fine in firefox

Comment: Ah, I am using proxy, maybe it is causing the issue. Thanks

Comment: Yep, that would do it.

Comment: Yup, that'd be my conclusion. Something in or around the browser is changing the URL that's actually being requested. The pages reflect the actually requested URL back in their header, so you can see what the browser or proxy has done. Use this info to report a bug to them.